# Client-side validation not working in ASP.net core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to enable client side validation in ASP.Net core 3.0 MVC application. When I submit my form from ajax request, client side validation is not working. However, when I directly post the form then it works.
Here is my model:

```
 public class RegisterViewModel 
    {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter first name")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter last name")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
```

Order of jquery libraries:

```
  <environment include="Development">
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </environment>
```

Form button:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" 
            onclick="accountFormScripts.createAccountRequest()" />
        </div>
```

I have tried to use add this line also in Startup.cs file under configureServcies

```
services.AddMvc().AddViewOptions(options =>
        {

            options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = true;


        });
```

But no luck :(

Please guide me, how to enable client side validation on Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo ,you could use `form.valid()` like below:

```
<form id="frm" asp-action="AjaxTest" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="AjaxTest" onclick="createAccountRequest()" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
</div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
 <script>
  function createAccountRequest()
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#frm').serialize();
    var $form = $('#frm');
    if ($form.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/AjaxTest",
            data:data,
            success: function () {
                alert("success!");
            }

        });
    }
    else {
        alert("fail");
    }    
  }
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]